# No Internet: wireless interface disabled by bios kvm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, bios

I suddenly have had Internet get lost on me

[image]

Woke up to having no WiFi or settings option in ububtu 18.04. Tried connecting router directly to laptop, didn't help.

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`ifconfig` gives
[image]
`lspci -vkm | grep -i wireless`
gives

`Device: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe`
`rfkill`
command gives output:

`0 wlan phy0 ublocked unblocked`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does your laptop have a physical switch to switch off Wi-Fi? Have you checked the switch position?

Comment: Problem with DHCP?  Both network devices ar up without IP address.